# Image not displaying in Django 1.8 template

Tags: django, image, static, media

I want to display images from the static folder inside a Django app called `index`. But it shows the icon in the browser which means that it cannot find the image in the path specified in the `<img src=""/>`. Here's my directory structure:

```
|-- db.sqlite3
|-- images
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- __init__.pyc
|   |-- settings.py
|   |-- settings.pyc
|   |-- urls.py
|   |-- urls.pyc
|   |-- wsgi.py
|   `-- wsgi.pyc
|-- index
|   |-- admin.py
|   |-- admin.pyc
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- __init__.pyc
|   |-- migrations
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   `-- __init__.pyc
|   |-- models.py
|   |-- models.pyc
|   |-- static
|   |   `-- index
|   |       `-- file2
|   |-- templates
|   |   `-- show.html
|   |-- tests.py
|   |-- urls.py
|   |-- urls.pyc
|   |-- views.py
|   `-- views.pyc
`-- manage.py
```

**views.py**

```
def show(request):
    return render(request, 'show.html', {})
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from index import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^show$', views.show),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**show.html**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<img src="{% static "index/file2" %}" alt="test_image"/>
```

I have tried to follow [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/) but obviously not doing it properly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you added STATICFILES_DIRS to your settings.py?

Comment: no.. just `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` which is added by default. Is that a necessity?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the problem though.
Could you add your settings.py to your question?

Comment: A few things, number one can you navigate directly to this image, ie... put the image in the url and see it by itself?  if so, than what is being put as the src location of this image that is not showing up?   This is most likely just an incorrect Static_Root setup.

Comment: I don't have a STATIC_ROOT, do I need one? I thought STATIC_URL was enough. I can't tell which one is for which purpose!

Comment: Is file really called `file2`? With no extension?

Comment: Yes it is called file2 because I don't know which format the file is on, could be a png, jpg, gif, so I can't fix a name for the file during upload. Or maybe I can, but I don't know how. Also, setting the STATIC_ROOT to 'static' did the trick. Thanks guys. Now I gotta learn how to resize it to fit the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set `STATIC_ROOT = 'static'` and it now displays the image on the web page.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of trials, finally I got it with a combination of answers from Stackoverflow. Really it is not straightforward. Phew! I'm happy and smiling though.
I've setup Django 1.8 on Windows with Apache and mod_wsgi (Xampp). 'vrsite' is my site. 'vrapp' is my app. The image finally showed from vrsite> vrsite > vrapp > static > vrapp >23-oracle.jpg My steps for getting the image displayed are below:
1. Directory structure:
C:...\myvirtualwebenv27_1\xampp\htdocs\vrsite\manage.py <---root

vrsite

```
  -- manage.py
  -- static
          --media
  -- static_dirs
          -- css
          -- img
                -- 23-oracle.jpg
          -- js
  -- static_root
          -- admin
               -- css
               -- img
               -- js
          -- css
          -- img
                -- 23-oracle.jpg
          -- vrapp
                 --23-oracle.jpg
  -- vrsite
          -- __init__.py
          -- settings.py
          -- urls.py
          -- wsgi.py
          -- vrapp
                 -- migrations
                 -- static
                         -- vrapp
                                -- 23-oracle.jpg

                 -- templates
                         -- index.html
                 -- __init.py__
                 -- admin.py
                 -- models.py
                 -- tests.py
                 -- views.py
```

2. settings.py

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'vrsite.vrapp',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'vrsite.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'vrsite.wsgi.application'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'static_root')
#STATIC_ROOT = 'static'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'static_dirs'),
)

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

3. urls.py

   from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

   ```
   from django.contrib import admin
   from django.conf import settings
   from django.conf.urls.static import static

   urlpatterns = [
       url(r'^$', 'vrsite.vrapp.views.home'),
   ] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
   ```
4. views.py

   from django.shortcuts import render

   from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

   ```
   def home(request):

           return render_to_response('index.html')
   ```
5. index.html

< body >

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<img src="{% static "vrapp/23-oracle.jpg" %}" alt = "My image"/>
```

< /body >

6. Run collect static as follows

   (myvirtualwebenv27_1) C:...\myvirtualwebenv27_1\xampp\htdocs\vrsite> C:...\myvirtualwebenv27_1\Scripts\python manage.py collectstatic

   You have requested to collect static files at the destination
   location as specified in your settings:

   ```
   C:\...\myvirtualwebenv27_1\xampp\htdocs\vrsite\static\static_root
   ```

   This will overwrite existing files!
   Are you sure you want to do this?

   Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes
   Copying C:...\myvirtualwebenv27_1\xampp\htdocs\vrsite\vrsite\vrapp\static\vrapp\23-oracle.jpg'

   1 static file copied to 'C:...\myvirtualwebenv27_1\xampp\htdocs\vrsite\static\static_root', 64 unmodified.

Comment: This is really comprehensive. Thanks for your effort @Sri Srii. But my problem was fixed with `STATIC_ROOT = 'static'`. However, can you show me how to resize the file while showing it? Not the original dimension of the image, but something I want to display. Let's say the image can be large or small, but I want to display it in 400x400 resolution.

Comment: @MiniGunnR, welcome ! In my case STATIC_ROOT = 'static' didn't work. If some one can explain why it works in some situation and not in some other, it would be useful knowledge. Regarding resize of image, I've not used so far. I've researched a bit though on creating thumb nails since I'm going to implement it shortly - please google with 'django thumbnails', you may hit some resources.